# Can't find how to print from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using the following code but when I try and print the information from the list it gives the error "<**main**.person object at 0x0000016162A50940>"
I am new to programming and can't find the solution as I don't even know the key terms to find this information.

I have been shown a similar post and have read through it and made some changes such as "Define **repr** but I am still stuck and when I add **repr** is now says "person() takes no argument". Would someone be able to give me some more guided and specific help. Thanks.

````
menu = ""
option = ""
class person:
      def __init__(self, First, Second, Number,Address1, Address2, Postcode):
          self.First = First
          self.Second = Second
          self.Number = Number
          self.Address1 = Address1
          self.Address2 = Address2
          self.Postcode = Postcode
          def new_Address(self):
              print(self.First + " " + self.Second + " " + self.Address1 + " " + self.Address2 + " " + self.Postcode)
              def __str__(self):
                  return f"{self.First} {self.Second} : {self.Number} : {self.Address1} : {self.Address2} : {self.Postcode} \n"







while option != "5":
    option = input("           Main Menu\n1. Add new address \n2. Change existing address \n3. View all addresses in database \n4. View specific address \n5. Quit")

    if option == "1":
         print ("Adding new address...")
         First = input("First Name ")
         Second = input("Second Name ")
         Number = input("Number ")
         Address1  = input("Street ")
         Address2 = input("Town ")
         Postcode = input("Postcode ")
         new_Address = person (First, Second, Number, Address1, Address2, Postcode)
         Addresses.append(new_Address)
         print("Address Added")


    elif option == "2":
           print("option 2")


    elif option == "3":
           print("All Addresses")
           for new_Address in Addresses:
               print(new_Address)
               input("Press Enter to Continue")


    elif option == "4":
           print("option 4")


    elif option == "5":
          print("See you next time!")
          break


    else:
           print("input not recognised. please try again...")```
````

Comment: Define `__repr__` on your class.